# What is the problem with my code Longest Collatz Sequence?

Tags: c, algorithm, brute-force, collatz

I have been trying to solve this problem :

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive
>   integers:
>
> n → n/2 (n is even)
>  n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence:
>  13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1)
>   contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz
>   Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.
>
> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?
>
> NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one
>   million.

and I implemented the below code, but this doesn't seem to give me the correct answer. It computes 910107 as the starting number that gives the longest chain, but the answer should be 837799.  What's wrong with it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int count=1;
    int last_count =0;
    int num=13;
    int temp;
    int Largest_Num=0;
    for(int i=num;i<1000000;i++)
    {
        temp = i;
        while(temp>1)
        {
            if(temp % 2 == 0)
            {
                temp/=2;
            }
            else
            {
                temp =(3*temp)+1;
            }
            count++;   

        }

        if(last_count < count)
        {
            last_count = count;
            Largest_Num = i;
        }

        count =1;
    }
    printf("%d\n",last_count);
    printf("%d",Largest_Num);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I get 910107 as the starting number that gives the longest chain but the answer should be 837799

*int* is too short to manage the large numbers you need for *temp*, you have overflow

That means your *int* is on 32 bits, and in that case *int* use only 31 bits for the positive numbers while you need 32

You can declare *temp* as an *unsigned int* (getting 1 bit more than an *int* because you only need positive numbers), or use a *long* if it is on 64 bits for you, or a *long long* to be sure to have at least 64 bits

Comment: `long long` is *guaranteed* to be at least 64 bits wide on conforming implementations. Saying that there is "a great chance" for that is not wrong, but it is slightly misleading.

Comment: This answer would also be improved by pointing out how the OP's code could be augmented to detect the overflow.  One does not always know in advance how wide a datatype one actually needs, so both the idea of detecting overflow in code and the mechanisms for doing that are useful information.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the max value for *temp* is for *i* valuing 704511, I was thinking that happens for instance for the higher prime number *i* can value, but not. I am not enough good in math to explain why there are numbers producing a long serial of odd number when multiplied by 3 more 1

Comment: It's not a math problem, @bruno, but a simple computational one.  `temp` gets assigned a larger value than its current one only here: `temp =(3*temp)+1`.  One need only check whether that will overflow  before performing it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for me this is not so simple because in the same loop the number can be divided by 2.  Of course having a loop up to 1000000 can introduce a doubt, but it is *only* 1000000 and not 1000000000, and here we are very close to no error, only 1 bit was missing.

Answer (score 1):

As @bruno observed in his answer, you are exceeding the capacity of your system's `int` data type.  The problem even hints that this is an issue you might encounter when it says:

> NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

How much above?  That's not clear from the problem, so "how can I determine what data type will be sufficient?" is a question that should immediately spring to mind.  Of course, the antecedent question "what data type should I choose?" is one that should *always* get at least a few moments of genuine attention.

Assuming no prior knowledge of the sequences you intend to compute, and having no clear way to determine reliable upper bounds for their elements in the general case, determining which data type will be sufficient requires actually performing (attempting) the computation and watching for overflow.  Alternatively, you can couch it as choosing a data type you think will be sufficient, and verifying as you go along that it in fact is sufficient.  If it's not, then you try again with a different data type.

Guarding against overflow is easy in this case.  The only variable that needs watching is `temp`, and its value increases only when you compute `temp =(3*temp)+1`.  You know what the maximum value of type `int` is (`INT_MAX`), and it is simple to determine algebraically the maximum value of `temp` for which that computation does not exceed `INT_MAX`: it is `(INT_MAX - 1) / 3`.  Thus, you can do this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#define TEMP_BOUND ((INT_MAX - 1) / 3)

// ...

            if(temp % 2 == 0) {
                temp /= 2;
            } else {
                assert(temp <= TEMP_BOUND);
                temp = (3 * temp) + 1;
            }
```

If you end up with an assertion failure (as you will when using type `int`), you can try again with a data type that supports a greater maximum value; just be sure then to update the `TEMP BOUND` macro appropriately for the new data type.

I should also observe that there is the alternative of performing your computations with an arbitrary-precision data type, such as is available from various third-party libraries (GMP, for example).  This will be *much* slower, though, and the code will be more complex, so for a case like this I do recommend the trial-and-error approach outlined above instead, at least up to the point that you determine that no built-in data type suffices for the problem.

Comment: The problem is when you have plenty of expressions it is penible because you need to cut some of them in several more simple expressions (to not lost a intermediate overflow) and to insert all the needed assert. In case of a doubt it is simpler to use a *typedef* to *int* (supposing that type) and use it to type elements , then to change *typedef* to *long long* or other and look if the result is the same to back to *int* (for performance reason) if possible.This is what I did with the OP code

Comment: Sure, @bruno, that's a reasonable mechanic for trying different data types, except inasmuch as you would need to recompute the bound separately.  But the point here is that what you describe is *not enough* if you don't already know the correct result of the computation being performed.

Comment: yes there is no guaranty, that way *hopes* to not have the same overflow effect with different types to detect if there is a problem, and is also if that cannot work even with *long long* I am in trouble and what to do ? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try This One

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checklongestchain(unsigned int number){
        int count = 0;
        while(number > 1){
                //printf(" %d  for %d\n",number,count);
                if(number % 2 == 0){
                        number = number / 2;
                        count++;
                }else{
                        number = (3 * number) +1;
                        count++;
                }
        }
        return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        unsigned int NUMBER, s;
        unsigned int i;
        int no = 0;
        int maxcount = 0;
        NUMBER = atoi(argv[1]);
        for (i = 1; i < NUMBER; i++) {
                no = checklongestchain(i);
                printf("Chain Length For : %d  for %d\n",no,i);
                if(no > maxcount){
                        maxcount = no;
                        s=i;
                        printf("Found New Largest Chain: %d  for %d\n",maxcount+1,s);
                }
        }
        printf("Found Largest Chain: %d  for %d\n",maxcount+1,s);
        return 0;
}
```

gcc prog.c -o prog

time ./prog 1000000